# Postgresql regexp_substring

Tags: postgresql, regexp-substr, regexp-like

I have a text as

```
Revision:3336179e1ebaa646cf281b7fb9ff36d1b23ce710$ modified $RevDate:10-04-2017 11:43:47$ by $Author:admin
```

Could you help me out with writing sql query that would get the first 6 chars of revision (333617) and date of RevDate (10-04-2017 11:43:47)? Thanks in advance.

I tried to get revision as

```
select (regexp_matches ('$Revision:3336179e1ebaa646cf281b7fb9ff36d1b23ce710$ modified $RevDate:10-04-2017 11:43:47$ by $Author:admin$', 
'^\$Revision:(a-z0-9+)\$'))[1]
```

No luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd rather go with substr and split_part (they are faster if I'm not mistaken):

```
t=# with v as (select 'Revision:3336179e1ebaa646cf281b7fb9ff36d1b23ce710$ modified $RevDate:10-04-2017 11:43:47$ by $Author:admin'::text l)
select substr(l,length('Revision:')+1,6),substr(split_part(l,'$',3),length('RevDate:')+1)
from v;
 substr |       substr
--------+---------------------
 333617 | 10-04-2017 11:43:47
(1 row)
```

Answer (score 0):

If regular expressions are preferred, the fixed-up expression would be:

```
select a[1] as revision, a[2] as date from (
  select regexp_matches('$Revision:3336179e1ebaa646cf281b7fb9ff36d1b23ce710$ modified $RevDate:10-04-2017 11:43:47$ by $Author:admin$',
 'Revision:([a-z0-9]{6}).*RevDate:([^\$]+)') a ) atbl;
```

Comment: the time part is not included in a[2], correct pattern would be 'Revision:([a-z0-9]{6}).*RevDate:([^\$]+)', thnks for your help

Comment: Thanks. Fixed answer